# Progressive quantity based shipping costs with a max cost in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

(How) can I set a max_fee for flat fee shipping costs in WooCommerce?

Adding this to the costs field in the flat fee settings of a shipping method works:

```
(1 * [qty]) + [fee min_fee = "2,5"]
```

(i.e. shipping costs 2,5 per order + 1 Euro per product) -> at least 3,5 and increasing + 1 for each product).

However, I want to charge 3,50 at minimum (for 1 item) and 4,50 at max (for 2 or more items). I.e. functionally this formula: `(3,5 * [qty])` **or** `[fee **max_fee** = "4,5"]`

Is this possible? / What is the correct syntax to use? I cannot find this anywhere. I only found [this reference ("add max_fee shortcode attribute for flat rate" / "allow max_fee in addition to min_fee in flat rate costs fields")](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11158) which seems to indicate that a feature request for a max_fee for flat fees (other than for percentages) is implemented. But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use available settings to charge a variable shipping cost as defined:

- **`3,50`** for the first item
- **`4,50`** for more than one item (2 or more)

So you will need to use the following custom hooked function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ){
    // Get cart items count
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Your cost settings
    $new_cost = $items_count > 1 ? 4.5 : 3.5;

    // Loop through shipping methods rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        $has_taxes = false;

        // Targeting "Flat rate" shipping methods
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $default_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;

            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            $rate_conversion = $new_cost / $default_cost;

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_conversion;
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Once the code is saved, go in your flat rate settings and set the rate cost to **`1.00`**:
>
> [image]
>
> Now the shipping rate will change from **`3.50`** *(for one item)* to **`4.50`** *(for more than one items)*

Comment: I have implemented your solution and it is perfect, many many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I can think of is to approximate a custom function using a tool like: https://mycurvefit.com/

Aim to get a function that approaches some limit by specifying data points - then the tool approximates a function to fit this data. This solution will not result in regular pretty fees, but would be a quick solution, if you don't want to get in the code.